# column not found in result set

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, jpql

I have a query that uses `JpaRepository`

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT count(user_name) AS user_count " +
                "FROM users " +
                "where status = 'B' ",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<Users> usersStatCount();
```

It gives me an error,

```
Could not execute query...
The column name user_name was not found in result set
```

But when I tried the query on pgadmin it is working fine.

And when I tried a simple

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * " +
                "FROM users " +
                "where status = 'B' ",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<Users> usersStatCount();
```

It is working fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the query returns a single value, not a row, that has to mapped to entity. Try the following:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT count(user_name) " +
                "FROM users " +
                "where status = 'B' ",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Long usersStatCount();
```

Comment: hi is that really Long type?

Comment: @Beginner it depends on the driver, usually it's `Long` or `BigInteger`

Comment: Hi it is working. What if  I have a query of Select user_no, count(user_name) as user_count from users where status = 'B' group by user_task_no

Comment: Then it's not a basic type and requires mapping. If the answer resolved your issue, consider upvoting / marking as correct;>